# Capturing Add To Cart Event

Tags: ajax, shopify

I am looking for a solution about how to call a javascript function when an item is added to cart on shopify via ajax. Product can be added from homepage, collection-page or product-page.

I am trying with this method but not working for me. These changes i am doing within the theme files "theme.liquid, product.liquid, collection.liquid"

Everytime product go to cart alert should done.

```
Shopify.onItemAdded = function(line_item) {
        alert('success');
      };
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Most times the code is to be added to `scripts.js` (or `script.js`) file, and often times, there'll always be something like this already. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [CartJs](https://cartjs.org/)... is does exactly what you need and has events etc for when things are added to cart